# Excel Macro: How do I copy info from multiple sheets to one while creating a unique identifier from sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

Here is my data set.

Sheet 1:

```
  FirstName       LastName       Email            Phone
  james           jones          jj@email.com     555-5555
  karen           johnson        kj@email.com     555-5556
  tony            brown          tb@email.com     555-5557
```

Sheet 2:

```
  FirstName       LastName       Email            Phone          Goal
  james           jones          jj@email.com     555-5555        200
  karen           johnson        kjoh@email.com   555-5556        500
  peter           white          pw@email.com     555-5558       1200
```

Sheet 3:

```
  FirstName       LastName       Email            Phone
  karen           johnson        kj@email.com     555-5556
  peter           white          pw@email.com     555-5558
  tim             thomson        tt@email.com     555-5559
```

Sheet 4 (result):

```
  FirstName       LastName       Email            Phone       Sheet2   Sheet3   Goal 
  james           jones          jj@email.com     555-5555    yes      no       200
  karen           johnson        kj@email.com,    555-5556    yes      yes      500
                                 kjoh@email.com
  tony            brown          tb@email.com     555-5557    no       no
  peter           white          pw@email.com     555-5558    yes      yes      1200
  tim             thomson        tt@email.com     555-5559    no       yes
```

See that Sheet 2 has some extra information I'd like to keep in the final sheet, the first sheet need not be listed in the final sheet, and that some people will have some unmatching data (as with karen johnson in the example above). With any three matching data points (i.e. - first + last + phone or first + last + email), we can assume a match.

Comment: If you have read the FAQs, seen JP's comment and its two upvotes, you will know that you are expected to have put some effort into your problem before asking for help. Is your problem that you do not know how to read data from one worksheet and write it to another?  If so, there are many answers from the last month or two that will help particularly with the tag `excel-vba`. Is your problem that you do not know how to compare and merge the data in sheets 1 to 3? If so, I think you will find people willing to help if make a start on the routine.

Answer (score 1):

Add the code below to your workbook. After running "MoveDataToSheet4", you will have the output as you describe on sheet4.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveDataToSheet4()
Dim rr As Range
Dim dta() As Variant
Dim topR As Long, foundrow As Long, mrow As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim LastR As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim OutPut() As Variant
Dim nmdRng As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")

With ws
    LastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim dta(1 To 6, 2 To LastR)
    For Each rr In .Range("A2:E" & LastR)
        dta(rr.Column, rr.Row) = rr.Value
    Next rr
End With

With ws2
    LastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    topR = UBound(dta, 2)
    ReDim Preserve dta(1 To 6, 2 To (topR + (LastR - 1)))
    For Each rr In .Range("A2:E" & LastR)
        dta(rr.Column, rr.Row + topR - 1) = rr.Value
        If rr.Column = 5 Then
            dta(6, rr.Row + topR - 1) = "Sheet2"
        End If
    Next rr
End With

With ws3
    LastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    topR = UBound(dta, 2)
    ReDim Preserve dta(1 To 6, 2 To (topR + (LastR - 1)))
    For Each rr In .Range("A2:E" & LastR)
        dta(rr.Column, rr.Row + topR - 1) = rr.Value
        If rr.Column = 5 Then
            dta(6, rr.Row + topR - 1) = "Sheet3"
        End If
    Next rr
End With

ReDim OutPut(1 To UBound(dta), 1 To 1)
For i = LBound(dta, 2) To UBound(dta, 2)

foundrow = Empty
For mrow = LBound(OutPut, 2) To UBound(OutPut, 2)
If OutPut(1, mrow) = dta(1, i) And OutPut(2, mrow) = dta(2, i) And i <> mrow Then
     foundrow = mrow
     Exit For
End If
Next mrow

Dim hold As Variant

If foundrow <> Empty Then
'it exists here and one other place so let's just merge them now
'merge it
    For x = LBound(OutPut) To UBound(OutPut) 'for each column
        If x = 1 Or x = 2 Then
            OutPut(x, foundrow) = dta(x, i)
        ElseIf x = 3 Or x = 4 Or x = 5 Or x = 6 Then
             If dta(x, i) <> OutPut(x, foundrow) Then
                OutPut(x, foundrow) = dta(x, i) & "," & OutPut(x, foundrow)
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Else
    ReDim Preserve OutPut(1 To UBound(dta), 1 To UBound(OutPut, 2) + 1)
    For x = LBound(OutPut) To UBound(OutPut) 'for each column
        OutPut(x, UBound(OutPut, 2)) = dta(x, i)
    Next x
End If
Next i
Dim Rng2 As Range
With ws4
    For Each Rng2 In .Range("A2:F" & UBound(OutPut, 2))
        Rng2.Value = OutPut(Rng2.Column, Rng2.Row)
        If Rng2.Column = 5 Then
            Rng2.Value = Replace(OutPut(Rng2.Column, Rng2.Row), ",", "")
        ElseIf Rng2.Column = 6 Then
            If InStr(Rng2.Value, "Sheet3") Then
                .Cells(Rng2.Row, Rng2.Column + 1) = "Yes"
                'Rng2.Value = ""
             Else
                .Cells(Rng2.Row, Rng2.Column + 1) = "No"
            End If
            If InStr(Rng2.Value, "Sheet2") Then
                Rng2.Value = "Yes"
                Else
                Rng2.Value = "No"
            End If

        End If
    Next Rng2
End With
End Sub
```

The output of Sheet4 will Look like the image below.

[image: Output of Sheet4]